# c program work on eclipse but fail on terminal because pause()

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, terminal

I am writing a c project with processes on eclipse in linux and when I debug and run it it works fine,
however when I run the program on the terminal(Where I need it to work) it have a problem that when I try to pause() a process and after that wake him up with signal he keep sleeping,in eclipse it wake up immediatly.any ideas?
sleep work well but it is not what I need

```
    signal(SIGHUP,sighup);  signal(SIGTERM, catchSigT);
    while(/*something*/){
     pid1=fork();//get son process id
         switch(pid1) {
             case -1:
                     printf("failed\n");
                     exit(1);
             case 0:
                  pause();
                    if(getpid()!=q->data[q->front]){pause();}
                        /*some code*/
                        kill(q->data[q->front],SIGHUP);
                        /*some code*/
                     kill(getppid(),SIGHUP);//only one process doing that,its inside if!!!!!!!
                    kill(getpid(),SIGKILL);
                        break;
             default:
                signal(SIGINT, sigproc);
                /*some code*/
                  kill(pid1,SIGTERM);
                 break;}}

     pause();

   /*some code and end of main*/

    void sighup()//wake up
    {  signal(SIGHUP,sighup); /* reset signal */
    }
    void catchSigT()
    {
      signal(SIGTERM, catchSigT);

    }
```

Comment: Why are you using the termination and hang-up signals for IPC? Why not the `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` signals? And why are you sending the `SIGKILL` signal to the child-process? Why not simply exit?

Comment: debug or release ??? how do you run it on terminal ?

Comment: Joachim-currect about SIGKILL i changed it,however this is not the problem.
 theadnangondal-i try both of them

Comment: EDIT:on terminal if i switch pause() for sleep(n) only in the end of the sleep it return only after n seconds and then print for example the handler message,even though it send earlier

Comment: I Am New here sorry,i did credit him now..

Comment: EDIT 2:I try to use SIGSTOP AND SIGCONT and same problem,in eclipse return from sleep in terminal stay sleep even after SIGCONT